# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'key'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter and i have 2 .py files, one called "account" and another called "account_support" im trying to build the gui in the "account.py" and then have all the functions related to that gui in "account_support.py"

this is account.py

```
import sys

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = 0
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = 1

import account_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = Tk()
    top = Add_Account (root)
    account_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_Add_Account(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = Toplevel (root)
    top = Add_Account (w)
    account_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Add_Account():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None


class Add_Account:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
        _ana2color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
        font9 = "-family {DejaVu Sans} -size 0 -weight normal -slant "  \
            "roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0"

        top.geometry("400x200+407+266")
        top.title("Add Account")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")



        self.menubar = Menu(top,font=font9,bg=_bgcolor,fg=_fgcolor)
        top.configure(menu = self.menubar)



        self.accName = Entry(top)
        self.accName.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.3, relheight=0.11, relwidth=0.44)
        self.accName.configure(background="white")
        self.accName.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.accName.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")

        self.Label1 = Label(top)
        self.Label1.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.1, height=38, width=176)
        self.Label1.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''Add Account''')

        self.Label2 = Label(top)
        self.Label2.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.3, height=18, width=126)
        self.Label2.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label2.configure(text='''Account Name:''')

        self.key = Entry(top)
        self.key.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.5, relheight=0.11, relwidth=0.44)
        self.key.configure(background="white")
        self.key.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.key.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")

        self.Label3 = Label(top)
        self.Label3.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.5, height=21, width=76)
        self.Label3.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label3.configure(text='''CMA Key:''')

        self.add = Button(top)
        self.add.place(relx=0.53, rely=0.7, height=26, width=107)
        self.add.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.add.configure(command=account_support.addaccount)
        self.add.configure(text='''Add Account''')

        self.helpButton = Button(top)
        self.helpButton.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.5, height=16, width=17)
        self.helpButton.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.helpButton.configure(command=account_support.question)
        self.helpButton.configure(text='''?''')






if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

and then for account_support.py

```
import sys
import webbrowser
import tkMessageBox

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = 0
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = 1



def addaccount():
    import account
    cmakey = account.Entry.key.get()
    acc = account.Entry.accName.get()
    print acc
    print cmakey
    sys.stdout.flush()


def question():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="CMA Key", message="")
    sys.stdout.flush()

def init(top, gui, *args, **kwargs):
    global w, top_level, root
    w = gui
    top_level = top
    root = top

def destroy_window():
    # Function which closes the window.
    global top_level
    top_level.destroy()
    top_level = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import account
    account.vp_start_gui()
```

when i try to get the value of account.py's key entry

with

```
def addaccount():
    import account
    cmakey = account.Entry.key.get()
    acc = account.Entry.accName.get()
    print acc
    print cmakey
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

i get the error

```
  File "/home/silicaandpina/VitaTools/psvimgtools-0.1-linux64/gui/psvimgtools/account_support.py", line 29, in addaccount
    cmakey = account.Entry.key.get()
AttributeError: class Entry has no attribute 'key'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're executing

```
cmakey = account.Entry.key.get()
acc = account.Entry.accName.get()
```

you're trying to access the `key` property of the `Entry` class of `Tkinter` in your module `account`. As you can tell by the error message, the `Entry` class doesn't have a property called `key`.

## The Solution

Change your `addaccount` function to

```
def addaccount(cmakey, acc):
    print acc
    print cmakey
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

As you can see, you're now receiving two parameters that are already the strings you want to use. Now, in `account`, change the button configuration line to

```
self.add.configure(command=lambda: account_support.addaccount(self.key.get(), self.accName.get()))
```